# Rendering Java Graphics to HTML

Tags: java, html, swing

I have a Swing Graphics2D object which I would like to render to HTML/JS/CSS. Is there a library or other way to do this?

I'm thinking of something similar to iText for exporting Java to PDF, but for exporting to HTML.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save it as a image (i.e. `jpg`) and then show this image with a simple `<img />` tag.

Comment: Use PNG, not JPG, for line art + other rendered graphics, JPG for photos.

Answer (score 2):

If your graphics rendering is primarily paths and lines and polygons and circles, this should translate easily to [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) (but I don't know of a library). Otherwise a bitmap is your safest bet (PNG should beat JPG for quality and filesize for rendered graphics).

---

edit: I haven't used it personally, but Apache Batik has a subclass of [Graphics2D](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html) which can be used to generate SVG files.